# Creating lists from csv files with rows with different amounts of entries

Tags: python

I have data in a csv file which looks like this:

```
fromaddress, toaddress, timestamp
sender1@email.com, recipient1@email.com, recipient2@email.com, 8-1-2015
sender2@email.com, recipient1@email.com, 8-2-2015
sender3@email.com, recipient1@email.com, recipient2@email.com, recipient3@email.com, recipient4@email.com, 8-3-2015
sender1@email.com, recipient1@email.com, recipient2@email.com, recipient3@email.com, 8-4-2015
```

Using Python, I would like to produce a txt file that looks like:

```
sender1_email.com, recipient1_email.com
sender1_email.com, recipient2_email.com
sender2_email.com, recipient1_email.com
sender3_email.com, recipient1_email.com
sender3_email.com, recipient2_email.com
sender3_email.com, recipient3_email.com
sender3_email.com, recipient4_email.com
sender1_email.com, recipient1_email.com
sender1_email.com, recipient2_email.com
sender1_email.com, recipient3_email.com
```

Ultimately, I imagine this whole process will take several steps. After reading in the csv file, I will need to create separate lists for fromaddress and toaddress (I am ignoring the timestamp column altogether). There is only 1 email address per row in the fromaddress column, however there are any number of email addresses per row in the toaddress column. I need to duplicate the fromaddress email address for each toaddress email address listed for each row. Once this done I need to replace all of the @ symbols with underscore (_) symbols. Finally, when I write the txt file, I need to add an extra space between each row so that it is "double-spaced"

I have not gotten very far as I'm a Python newbie and I'm stuck on the first step. The following code is duplicating the fromaddress for each individual character in the toaddress column instead of each individual email address. I also need help with the toaddress list as well. Can anyone help?

```
import csv
fromaddress = []
toaddress = []

with open("filename.csv", 'r') as f:
    c = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
    for row in c:
        for item in row[1]:
            fromaddress.append(row[0]);

print(fromaddress)
```

Everyone, thanks for all of your help! I tried all your code but unfortunately I'm not getting the output I need. Instead of getting this (what I want):

```html
sender1_email.com, recipient1_email.com
sender1_email.com, recipient2_email.com
sender1_email.com, recipient3_email.com
sender2_email.com, recipient1_email.com
sender3_email.com, recipient1_email.com
sender3_email.com, recipient2_email.com
```

I'm getting this:

```html
sender1_email.com,"recipient1_email.com, recipient2_email.com, recipient3_email.com"
sender2_email.com,"recipient1_email.com"
sender3_email.com,"recipient1_email.com, recipient2_email.com"
```

There is only 1 element in each "fromaddress" row, but there are multiple elements in each "toaddress" row.  Basically, I have to pair each recipient address with the correct sender address. I think I'm not getting the right output because of the ( " ) double quotation marks in the csv file to surround all of the sender addresses in each row.

Comment: Thanks Will, however I need to look at the second column and count the number of email addresses in the "toaddress" column.

Comment: hi, I completed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in c:   
    for item in row[1]:
        fromaddress.append(row[0]);
```

`for item in row[1]` is going to only look at the second element in each row.  If you want to loop over each row, then assign column elements to variables, you want this:

```
for row in c:   
    fromaddress.append(row[0]);
    toaddress.append(row[1]);
    # etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
output = open("output.txt", "w")

for line in f.readlines()[1:]: # splitting file into lines, excluding the first one
    fields = line.split(", ") # splitting line into separate fields

    for mail in fields[1:len(fields)-1]: # iterating on recepients (excluding first and last element from "fields" list)
        output.write(fields[0] + " " + mail + "\n")

f.close()
output.close()
```

Comment: I said "should" but i tested it, it does works, you just need to change "file.txt" parameter with the filepath of the file you need to work on

Answer (score 0):

When the first email address is always the sender address and the last item in a row is always an useless value (date), you could do the following.

test.txt input file

```
sender1@email.com, recipient1@email.com, recipient2@email.com, 8-1-2015
sender2@email.com, recipient1@email.com, 8-2-2015
sender3@email.com, recipient1@email.com, recipient2@email.com, recipient3@email.com, recipient4@email.com, 8-3-2015
sender1@email.com, recipient1@email.com, recipient2@email.com, recipient3@email.com, 8-4-2015
```

python code

```
import csv

storage = [] #here we store our sender-receiver pairs

with open('test.txt','rb') as f: #open the input text file
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','): #loop through every line of the input file
        storage.extend([(row[0].replace('@','_'),x.replace('@','_')) for x in row[1:-1]]) #add a sender-receiver pair to the storage list

#here we loop through the storage list and write line by line to  the `new.text` file.
for pair in storage:
    with open("new.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(pair[0] + pair[1] + ' \n\n') #double new line!
```

output in new.txt

```
sender1_email.com recipient1_email.com 

sender1_email.com recipient2_email.com 

sender2_email.com recipient1_email.com 

sender3_email.com recipient1_email.com 

sender3_email.com recipient2_email.com 

sender3_email.com recipient3_email.com 

sender3_email.com recipient4_email.com 

sender1_email.com recipient1_email.com 

sender1_email.com recipient2_email.com 

sender1_email.com recipient3_email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create separate lists to do what you want, plus you can use the `csv` module for both reading the input csv file *and* writing the txt output file:

```
import csv

with open('mail.csv','rb') as inf, open('mail.txt', 'wb') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    next(reader)  # skip header row
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    for row in reader:
        row = row[:-1]  # remove trailing date
        sender = row[0].replace('@', '_')
        writer.writerows(([sender, recipient.replace('@', '_')]
                            for recipient in row[1:]))
```

Comment: Thanks martineau, I tried your code but unfortunately I'm not getting the output I need.

Comment: My code produces exactly the output you said you wanted, not what you claim you're getting, when run with your input file. I suggest you try it again.